# Connecting a POS Terminal To a web application

Tags: php, terminal, credit-card

I have a spectra t1000 POS Terminal I want to connect it to my Web application.
I gave it the amount that must be paid and the user only pass his card and enter the pin, Then it sends me back the response with a true or false operation.
I want to connect it using PHP, JSON if it is not possible, I can use any other web coding language that can help.

Comment: These days, almost every hardware/website/application that captures/processes data has an API (a script that fetches the data and prepares it to in encoded JSON to be accessed by external scripts). Accessing JSON is not limited to PHP. You can conveniently use PHP in case your hardware (POS) facilitates this. Or else you will have to manually export the data and convert it to the JSON.

Comment: This POS has no API , What shall i do ?

Comment: I remember working with POS in the year 2004. There must be an option to schedule data export recurrently. Try to get that option. Check the available formats it exports the data in. Once you find that, post it here.